# Twig Template Inheritance Issues

Tags: twig, craftcms

I'm trying to setup a clean structure for my Craft CMS install, but having issues with some **very** basic twig and a nice way to structure my things.

[See this gist](https://gist.github.com/tommysvr/4dc65bf8919d67738d8fe4f7b59c1eb2) - why would my Navbar not show in this example?

Even better, I would like to structure my site like this - but it doesn't show anything? - [another gist](https://gist.github.com/tommysvr/48e509561477ce3e62645b1316ead37a)

Am I mixing the extend/block pattern the wrong way somehow? This feels so very basic and thus it's extremely frustrating. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first gist, in `index.twig`, you extend `base.twig` correctly. However, you don't specify the contents of the `navbar` block, so the block defaults to the empty content that is set in `base.twig`.

You can change `base.twig` to include `navbar.twig` using the [`include` function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/include.html):

```html
...
  <div id="content">
    {% include "navbar.twig" %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
...
```

You should also not extend `base.twig` in `navbar.twig` to prevent infinite recursion (`base` includes `navbar`, which extends `base`, which includes `navbar`, ...).

If you want the navbar to be overridable in `index.twig` and other files, you can retain the `navbar` block in `base.twig` and set its default contents to include `navbar.twig`:

```html
...
  <div id="content">
    {% block content %}
      {% include "navbar.twig" %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
...
```

Then, in `index.twig`, if you omit `{% block navbar %}{% endblock %}`, the navbar will use the contents from `navbar.twig`. Or you can also override the `navbar` block's contents:

```html
{% extends "base" %}

{% block navbar %}
  <h2>Overridden navbar</h2>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Main content</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

---

In your second gist, in `index.twig`, you can change `{% block head %}{% endblock %}` to `{% include "head.twig" %}` and so on. In `head.twig` and other files, you should again not extend `index.twig` to prevent infinite recursions.

I recommend taking a look at [Twig's documentation about the `extends` tag](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/extends.html) to see how blocks and templates actually work. In your two gists, blocks and templates are not used correctly.